# Change the color of a pixel in a canvas, Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Someone know if it's possible to change the color of a pixel in a canvas without using un object, so without using something like `canvas.create_oval` or `canvas.create_rectangle` ?

Comment: The canvas is not a matrix, use an image for doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `tkinter` itself, it's impossible.

Even if you manage to change a pixel on canvas window (which is possible with X11 and Windows APIs in a platform-dependent way), you'd have to ensure it's repainted properly.

You can, of course, `place` a `frame` of size 1x1 over the canvas, with a background color you want. This way, pixel is "changed" and no canvas object is created. If there's a real (though strange) problem behind a question, this trick could be a solution.

Comment: It's work but it's do the same thing as with `canvas.create_rectangle`, when there is a lot of colored pixels, the canvas is lagging

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to color a pixel other than to create a 1x1 pixel object of some sort. And yes, at some point you will experience performance problems. The canvas simply wasn't designed to be used this way.

If you're really needing to create a large area in which you can manage individual pixels, you can create a canvas with a single image that is the same size as the canvas. You can then set the color of individual pixels on the image through the photo image interface.